# Class variables values aren't being updated

Tags: ios, swift, class, struct

I have an iOS app written in Swift.
In this app, I have multiple variables that I need them to be accessible in every ViewController. The problem is that I can't pass them in the `prepare(for segue:, sender:)` because I'm talking about 20 variables.

I tried putting them in a class named `GlobalVars`, so that on the initial ViewController I load the data from the DB into the variables. In this ViewController, this is how I have declared the class variable:

```
var vars: GlobalVars = GlobalVars()
```

And then, in the `viewDidLoad()` function, I load the data into the class's variables.

In the other ViewControllers, I declare at the beginning the following variable:

```
var vars: GlobalVars = LoadingViewController().vars
```

The problem starts already in the LoadingViewController. The problem is that apparently the data isn't being saved into the class's variables.

In this class I have initial values for every variable, but empty ones. For example, arrays are declared as `[]`.

How can I make the variables accessible from every ViewController? I also tried it with struct instead of class, but that didn't work well too.

Comment: `LoadingViewController().vars` it is not the same instance of your view controller

Comment: Just add your 20 variable into a single object and pass it, would that be better?

Comment: The fact that it's called `GlobalVars` should tell you that this is a bad idea. @Tj3n is right - create a struct and pass it between view controllers.

Comment: Still, if you want the changes to be reflected in every class, it's better to use singleton or global variable or db, I think the OP already using db, but how he working with it seems wrong, just fetch the data again in every class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1 - Global variable** (Not recommended)

Declare them as global variables outside any class.

```
var vars: GlobalVars = GlobalVars()
```

**Method 2 - Shared Instance**

Declare them as static variables inside the class:

```
class GlobalVars {
    static var shared: GlobalVars = GlobalVars() 

    // Your variables and other stuff
}
```

You can access the variables by using the class name followed by `.` operator.

```
GlobalVars.shared.variable = // Store something
```

Comment: You shouldn't suggest the use of global vars

Comment: @LeoDabus i know it's bad. But it is a possible solution. That is why i listed it. I have edited the answer to show that it is not recommended.

Comment: Regarding your second method you should create just one shared static instance. You should take a look at Cocoa Design Pattern "singleton" https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cocoa_design_patterns/managing_a_shared_resource_using_a_singleton

Comment: Will I be able to update the variables's value this way?

Comment: @LeoDabus updated, thanks. I don't know how that skipped my train of thought. I just answered something yesterday that required a static instance.

Comment: @IdoNaveh yes. You can directly call them like how i have shown in the last line.

Comment: @AshleyMills sometimes it is convenient to use global variables, than to create a class and static instance. So it is still a valid solution to his problem. So i included it.

Comment: @AshleyMills Does it hurt to be aware of a possible solution? And i did not perpetuate poor programming practise because even if it is not the optimal solution for this problem (I have edited to say that it is not a recommended practice after it was pointed out by @LeoDabus), it doesn't hurt to be aware of an alternative. So i'm gonna leave the answer just like that no matter how many downvotes i get because it is **relevant**.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri just flag Ashley's comments for unkind and unfriendly. They need a little more courtesy in getting their point across. We all are trying to build a community where we can make mistakes and learn, do NOT feel regret for your efforts

Comment: I have just checked your solution, but unfortunately, after I have loaded again the items from my DB, the data hasn't been changed, and it shows the same data yet. Is it related to something with resuming the ViewController's activity or something?

Comment: @IdoNaveh How have you loaded the items from DB? Can you show the code by editing the question? How are you changing the data?

Comment: I'm loading it the same way I always load. When the app initially loads, all the data is loaded ok, but when the data is changed and it gets again to the LoadingViewController, the data isn't being changed

Comment: @IdoNaveh Please show the code where you do that so that i can check if you are doing something wrong?

Comment: I change the variables values just as you told: `GlobalVars.shared.variable = "new value"`

Comment: @IdoNaveh then it should work fine, that is why i asked if you can share the full code.

Answer (score 1):

Global vars are bad, but so are shared instances (singletons). Singletons live forever, are accessible from anywhere in your code, make unit testing hard, etc etc.

Instead consider dependency injection.

Ideally:

```
final class MutableVariables {
    var firstVariable: String
    var secondVariable: String
}

final class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var variables: MutableVariables

    init(injectedDependency: MutableVariables) {
        self.variables = injectedDependency
    }

    func doStuff() {
        self.variables.firstVariable = "foo"
    }
}   

func startMyApp() {
    let variables = MutableVariables() //keep hold of this somewhere
    let viewController = ViewController(injectedDependency: variables)
    present(viewController)

    let anotherViewController = ViewController(injectedDependency: variables)
    present(viewController)
}
```

But since you're using a storyboard with a segue:

```
final class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var variables: MutableVariables!

    func inject(dependency: MutableVariables) {
        self.variables = injectedDependency
    }

    func doStuff() {
        self.variables.firstVariable = "foo"
    }
}   

final class MasterController {

    let variables = MutableVariables()

    func startMyApp() {

        let viewController = ViewController()
        present(viewController)

        let anotherViewController = ViewController()
        present(viewController)
    }

    func segueFinished(for viewController: ViewController) {
        viewController.inject(dependency: self.variables)
    }
}
```

Of course, it's just as problematic for multiple `ViewController`s to be directly mutating the same set of variables. Consider having each `ViewController` delegating to some parent object (i.e. `MasterController` above), which is the only object which has the ability to alter your variables.